# Use VSCode for C++ Project Inside Conda Environment on MacOS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, conda

I have a c++ project that uses dependencies I installed via conda (geant4 and root).
I'm using CMake to manage the project and VSCode as the editor.

Right now VSCode has no idea what is going on, highlighting all the dependencies as "file cannot be found" and the CMake extension can't find the CMake executable. Both is very understanable since they live in the conda env.

When googling for a way to deal with this I found nothing that was helpful, pretty much only Python stuff and some forum post saying that on linux you supposedly can just start VSCode via the command line inside the conda env and it should be fine.

How can I do this on Mac OS and with C++? I'd love to get proper hints for the libraries and for the CMake extension to work.

Comment: Read the documentation of the CMake extension. Since there is more than one CMake extension for VSCode, I don't know which one you mean. For VSCode you have to configure IntelliJ. You can manually configure the dependencies or configure CMake to generate a `compile_commands.json` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) and use this file in VSCode (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference). You should also read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: And https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux

Comment: Thanks @jabaa ! This way I can get compilation to work. But is there a way for autocomplete to work with the libraries I'm using from conda? I didn't find anything on that in the vs code cpp documentation.

Comment: I don't understand what this means? What does _"autocomplete to work with the libraries"_ mean?

Comment: In my first comment, I wrote IntelliJ, but I meant IntelliSense. That are two completely different things.

Comment: Sorry I meant stuff like tab autocompletion for function names etc. But I think that's what the intelisense is for right?

Comment: Yes, it's for autocompletion and other hints.

Comment: Thanks you so much with this help I managed to get it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Intellisense: add /path/to/conda/env/include to Extensions/C++/IntelliSense/Include Path in the vscode settings

For CMake:

- add `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/path/to/conda/env")` to the CMakeLists.txt
- set Extensions/CMake Tools/Cmake Path to /path/to/conda/env/bin/cmake in the vscode setting

Do a clean build